# Permission-less Side-Chain Concepts?

Tags: decentralization, sidechains

Pretty much every major side-chain concept seems to imply a permission governed finality system which is not ideal long-term for lots of hopefully obvious reasons.
Is there any good explanation as for why this is in the existing models?

Are there any that I have missed that do not have any sense of permission?

I am personally skeptical of the idea that permission is universally required for side-chain type functionality.